# 20.04.1 LTS up to date freezes when Firefox is opened

Tags: 20.04, firefox

Ubuntu info:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

Computer info:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G86 [GeForce 8400 GS] (rev a1)
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.4 present.

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 8 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
    Product Name: EP43-DS3R
    Version: x.x
    Serial Number:
```

Problem:

When Firefox is started the computer freezes up.  A remote login/terminal shows:

```
18279    2454  1 14:22 ?        00:00:37 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -new-window
18409   18279  0 14:23 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 2 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 160 -prefMapSize 238611 -parentBuildI
18430   18279  0 14:23 ?        00:00:03 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 3 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 254 -prefMapSize 238611 -parentBuildI
18464   18279  0 14:23 ?        00:00:01 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 4 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 5006 -prefMapSize 238611 -parentBuild
18549   18279  0 14:23 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 5 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 6006 -prefMapSize 238611 -parentBuild
root
```

I have deleted and reloaded Firefox but the problem is still there.
If left for 20 mins plus the computer returns and Firefox and be closed but if restarted it again locks up.  Sometimes with the message it can't locate earlier tabs.

This problem just arose when I tried Firefox the system has been together for sometime and is used for FreeCAD mostly.

Any other information that would help I'll try to provide.

Comment: How much RAM is there? Have you checked that the RAM is good and that the file system is good? Can you check what keeps the computer busy (which processes) while firefox keeps the computer frozen?

Comment: 4 gb of ram, /dev/sda1        2048 976769023 976766976 465.8G 8e Linux LVM,   dev/sdb1  *       2048   2099199   2097152     1G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2       2099200 976769023 974669824 464.8G 8e Linux LVM

Answer (score 0):

After much testing and lots of bad words, this looks like a hardware problem with the computer.  So the fix maybe a new computer.

**Edit:**

Fixed the problem by upgrading the video card. After adding a NVIDIA Corporation GK208B [GeForce GT 710] (rev a1) and everything is good now.